# Condensing lines of code

Tags: java, optimization, indexing

If I have the following lines of code below is there any way I can condense this into 1 or 2 lines and use a loop or something similar?  There is over 100 indexes so it's a large amount of text to write out.

```
unrlzdPnl = 
(((Positions[0].GetProfitLoss(Closes[0][0], PerformanceUnit.Points))*200)
+ ((Positions[1].GetProfitLoss(Closes[1][0], PerformanceUnit.Points))*200)
+ ((Positions[2].GetProfitLoss(Closes[2][0], PerformanceUnit.Points))*200)
+ ((Positions[3].GetProfitLoss(Closes[3][0], PerformanceUnit.Points))*200)
+ ((Positions[4].GetProfitLoss(Closes[4][0], PerformanceUnit.Points))*200)
+ ((Positions[5].GetProfitLoss(Closes[5][0], PerformanceUnit.Points))*200)
+ ((Positions[6].GetProfitLoss(Closes[6][0], PerformanceUnit.Points))*200)
);
```

Comment: what is the language? Java ? We edited to add that, please add more details your question.

Comment: Is this question answered? Did you mean something different?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get it but I'd say:

```
int unrlzPnl = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nb_indices; i++) {
    unrlzdPnl += Positions[i].GetProfitLoss(Closes[i][0],
                                            PerformanceUnit.Points);
}
unrlzPnl *= 200;
```

**EDIT #1:**

Don't forget to initialize `unrlzPnl` before the loop. If you want to see what happens at each iteration (assuming you're using `Java`):

```
int unrlzPnl = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nb_indices; i++) {
    System.out.println("Iteration " + i + ":");
    System.out.println("unrlzdPnl (old): " + unrlzdPnl);
    unrlzdPnl += Positions[i].GetProfitLoss(Closes[i][0],
                                            PerformanceUnit.Points);
    System.out.println("unrlzdPnl (new): " + unrlzdPnl + "\n");
}
return unrlzPnl * 200;
System.out.println("unrlzdPnl (final value): " + unrlzdPnl);
```

---

**EDIT #2:**

Okay, if you really want it as compact as possible and avoid initialization each time you call the function:

```
int MyFunction(int nb_indices) {
    if (1 > nb_indices)
        return 0;

    unrlzdPnl = Positions[0].GetProfitLoss(Closes[0][0],
                                           PerformanceUnit.Points);

    for (int i = 1; i < nb_indices; i++)
        unrlzdPnl += Positions[i].GetProfitLoss(Closes[i][0],
                                                PerformanceUnit.Points);

    return unrlzPnl * 200;
}
```

Comment: No I think you got it, I just don't know simple code, the += is what I was needing.  Thank You

Comment: Actually I seem to be getting different results, is for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {unrlzdPnl += Positions[i].GetProfitLoss(Closes[i][0],PerformanceUnit.Points);}  equivalent to.. unrlzdPnl = ((Positions[0].GetProfitLoss(Closes[0][0],PerformanceUnit.Points)) + (Positions[1].GetProfitLoss(Closes[1][0],PerformanceUnit.Points)));

Comment: Yeah, it should be. If you want to make sure, you can print out the line inside the loop, that'll show you exactly how many times the program loops along with the values of the variables at each iteration.

Comment: Don't forget the initialization of `unrlzdPnl` and the final multiplication by `200` before comparing the results. Also, I implicitly assumed that unrlzdPnl is an `integer`, but if that's not the case, you should use the appropriate type and initialization.

Comment: Ok I got it, I initialized unrlzdPnl and was thinking that coveredit but I needed to also have it inside the method to reset it on each update of the method.  Saves a lot of code.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you can move the init inside the first part of the for loop but that doesn't change anything as to what the code does. Unless you have a reason not to, I advise you to prefer a readable code over a compact code anytime, especially since the code will ended up modified by the compiler. Besides, I honestly don't think you can factorize this code any more than.it already is...

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer with a code slightly more compact. But I seriously doubt it is that significant a change. Most compilers do a lot of optimizations by default.